# Angular Material Left Side Nav Sapce Issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm following angular material starter application example, but in side nav bar there is lot of extra space between list items. When I open the page in Mozilla I don't have the issue but It doesn't loook good in Chrome.

```
<md-toolbar layout="row">      
      <h1>Angular Material - Starter App</h1>
    </md-toolbar>


    <div layout="row" flex>

        <md-sidenav layout="column" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')"
                    class="md-whiteframe-z2">
         <md-list>

          <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">Favorites</md-subheader>
          <md-list-item class="md-1-line">
             <h3>Bio</h3>         
          </md-list-item>
             <md-divider></md-divider>
          <md-list-item class="md-1-line">
             <h3>Professional</h3>        
         </md-list-item>                

         </md-list>
        </md-sidenav>

        <md-content flex id="content"> 
           <p>Main Content will come here</p>
        </md-content>

    </div>
```

[image: In Chrome]

[image: In Mozilla]

Comment: Looks okay in Chrome - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/jrVLeB

Comment: So what I was missing @camden_kid markup is exactly the same

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that you use `class="md-1-line"`. As far as I know only classes `md-2-line` and `md-3-line` exist, but I don't think that is the problem. The only other thing I can suggest is that you inspect the CSS in the console to get a clue to the problem.